# A faster way of finding unbiased estimators for this linear model

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients

No access to computers or calculators is available for this problem.

Consider the following linear model

$$Y_1 =\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 + \theta_4 + \theta_5 + \theta_6 + \epsilon_1\\
Y_2 =\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 - \theta_4 - \theta_5 - \theta_6 + \epsilon_2\\
Y_3 =\theta_1 - \theta_2 - \theta_3 + \theta_4 + \theta_5 - \theta_6 + \epsilon_3\\
Y_4 =\theta_1 - \theta_2 - \theta_3 - \theta_4 - \theta_5 + \theta_6 + \epsilon_4\\
Y_5 = -\theta_1 + \theta_2 - \theta_3 + \theta_4 - \theta_5 + \theta_6 + \epsilon_5\\
Y_6 = -\theta_1 + \theta_2 - \theta_3 - \theta_4 + \theta_5 - \theta_6 + \epsilon_6$$

...with standard assumptions: $ \mathbf{\epsilon} = (\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_6)', E(\mathbf{\epsilon}) = 0, Var(\mathbf{\epsilon}) = \sigma^2I$

We need to find unbiased estimators for all $\theta_i$, and moreover the Best Linear Unbiased Estimator for $\theta_1 - 2\theta_2 + \theta_3$.

My attempt: recognising that the OLS estimator for the coefficient matrix $\mathbf{\theta}$ is unbiased for each individual coefficient, I calculated $(X^TX)^{-1}X^{T}Y$. The resulting calculations are very lengthy, even though some extra effort can be avoided by noting that $X^TX$ is a block-diagonal matrix.

Am I missing a trick here which allows a faster computation? Or is this really the best that can be done?

Edit: for reference, the calculated OLS matrix looks like so:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $

From what I understand, this matrix adds/subtracts $Yi$ values so that the $\theta_j, j\neq i$ values vanish for each estimated $\theta_i$.